# use SQL to find out the total amount of claims per age group per education level

Tags: sql, database

[[image]

How can I generate the result like:

```
Age group   Education   Claim amount
<20        High School   12345
           Bachelors     67890
           Master        2131323
           PhD            2141241  

20-30      High School
           Bachelors
           Master
           PhD
30-40      High School
           Bachelors
           Master
           PhD

40-50      High School
           Bachelors
           Master
           PhD



>60        High School
           Bachelors
           Master
           PhD


SELECT age_group, EDUCATION, SUM(CLM_AMT)
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN AGE <20 THEN '<20'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-30'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-40'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-50'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN '50-60'
            WHEN AGE > 60 THEN '>60'

        END age_group
    FROM Car.Claim)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting age_group, Education and Clm_Amt from a sub-select. OK so far. The problem is that the sub-select doesn't include Education or Clm_Amt.

```
SELECT age_group, EDUCATION, SUM(CLM_AMT)
FROM(
    SELECT Education, Clm_Amt,
        CASE
            WHEN AGE <20 THEN '<20'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20-30'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30-40'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40-50'
            WHEN AGE BETWEEN 50 AND 60 THEN '50-60'
            WHEN AGE > 60 THEN '>60'

        END age_group
        FROM Car.Claim)
group by age_group, Education
```

You need the `group by` clause to tell it when to show the total Clm_Amt - for each uniqueu value of age_group + Education. All totals like this are called aggregates, and include things like Max, Min, Avg, and you need to specify in them in the `group by` clause.

In fact, if you have an aggregate in the select clause, anything which isn't an aggregate must be in the group by: the order of them specifies which is the major grouping (in this case age_group) and the order of minor groupings (if any). if you had `group by Education, age_group`, then it would age_groups for each education level rather than education for each age group.